# ZfcUser Redirect to page of my choice after Registration

Tags: zend-framework2, registration, zfcuser

I have been trying to redirect to a page/route of my choice after zfcuser registration. Currently it redirects to the login page.

I was able to make changes on the init event where I am now using the recaptcha instead of figlet.

I have added a listener on my module's bootstrap method on zfcuser's register event. But not sure what to do afterwards so that I can redirect to a page of my choice after user registers. Any help would be much appreciated as it would also help me alot on my basic understanding of zf2.

Here is my bootstrap code (nothing much there) on my module class on zfcuser register event:

```
$zfcServiceEvents = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('zfcuser_user_service')->getEventManager();
$zfcServiceEvents->attach('register', function($e) use ($app) {

// ...............

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to return a `Response`-Object from that listener. Whenever there is a return Object of type `Response`, then the application workflow stops and the `Response` is returned.

What you wanna be doing is to create said `Response`-Object, give it the status redirect and add the header for redirection ;)

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you. Although I would have liked if zfcuser module had configuration options such as 'login_redirect_route', 'logout_redirect_route'.